# Ignoring quotation marks within text string in Powershell

Tags: powershell, parentheses

I have this snippet of code

```
     Get-Content -Tail 0 -Wait -Encoding "UTF8" $log | 
       Select-String "GroupEvents: Linedup for group “(.*)”, subgroup" |
        % {$_.matches.groups[1].value} |
         Write-SlowOutput -outputFile $output -waitFor $delay
```

Note in Select-String I am trying to extract the text within the parentheses. Note the parentheses have quotation marks at either end. If I remove these then the returned text has quotation marks. So my question is how to remove the quotation marks without the script failing.

The snippet is part of a PowerShell script which searches the log file of a game on my pc and writes the extracted text to a text file.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE - Am I right in thinking I use the grave accent to prevent the quotation marks being used to delimit?

Comment: Parenthesis are special charachters when it comes to regex. That's why you should _escape_ them with a "\" (backslash) if you want to find them literally.

Comment: Can you give an example of a line of the source data, and what you want to extract? The combination `.*` will try to match everything, which is why it likely isn't working as expected for you.

Comment: So the text I want will be something like Group Run. But it’s really not important what the text actually is. When I extract it, it comes with quotation marks around it. So I want to get rid of them and just leave the text. I am thinking of trying the grave accent in front of each quotation mark.

Comment: @StephenCousins It might be helpful when you share a little example of a search text and the expected output. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand, I think the issue is that you have to escape the quotation marks inside the `Select-String` statement. One way to do that is with the grave accent (`) character inside double quoted strings:

```
Select-String "GroupEvents: Linedup for group `"(.*)`", subgroup" |
```

Another one would be to use single quotes on the outside of the string, which require no escaping:

```
Select-String 'GroupEvents: Linedup for group "(.*)", subgroup' |
```

I personally prefer using the single quoted strings on the outside, as it makes your code more readable. So your final code would be:

```
Get-Content -Tail 0 -Wait -Encoding "UTF8" $log | 
   Select-String 'GroupEvents: Linedup for group "(.*)", subgroup' |
    % {$_.matches.groups[1].value} |
     Write-SlowOutput -outputFile $output -waitFor $delay
```

Comment: Your solution still applies (+1), but note that the quotation marks embedded in the string in the question are typographical quotation marks: `“` (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, [`U+201C`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c)) and `”` (RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, [`U+201D`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d))